# Finding best function approximation using only $3$ basis functions?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm given six data points, namely:

$[0,2],[1,4],[2,3],[3,3.5],[4,5],[5,4]$

and I need to find a function approximation that only uses $3$ basis functions.

I was thinking about using a combination of a sine function and a linear function with a constant.

The following picture illustrates this, where I used the function $1.5 + 2\sin(20\pi x) + 1.1 x$, which looks as if this could yield a good fit with the right parameters.

[image: Manual fit]

So basically I would like to solve the following optimisation problem:

$$argmin_{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3} \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^6(a_0+a_1\sin(a_2\pi x_i) + a_3 x_i -y_i)^2}$$

First of all is this an approach that is likely to yield a good fit? If it isn't, what approach would you suggest and if it is, how can I optimise the function$?$

Comment: Did you try to find the best parameters for $a + b\sin(c\pi x) + dx$? The problem seems to be that you predefined the frequency...

Comment: Yes I am. Is that a bad approach?

Comment: Predefining the frequency is certainly bad. Substitute other frequencies and plot. You will see how much better approximations you would get. The best would be to minimize the parameters in $a+b\sin(cx+d)+f.$

Comment: As far as the optimization problem: you, please, remove the square root sign. The result will be the same...

Comment: What do you call a basis function ? If you put no restriction on what a basis function can be, then a Lagrangian interpolant on the given points can do !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think in this exercise you should only take a linear combination of 3 functions that take x as input. So we would have three terms $\sum_{i=1}^3a_if_i(x)$. I just skimmed through the wiki article on Lagrange interpolation, and it looks as if you would need a basis function for every point. Or is this possible with 3 "basis functions" in the sense just defined having 6 data points?

Comment: @eager2learn: you still don't tell what a basis function is and the question is meaningless. If you take $f_i$ such that it passes through the six given points, one term is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right. This is for a signal processing class, which isn't rigorous at all, and we weren't even given a definition for basis function. I will fit a lagrange polynomial and declare that as my basis function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, interpolation with a quadratic (to respect the 3 basis functions constraint) yields:

$$
y=2.32143+0.832143 x-0.0892857 x^2
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I've did this, but this doesn't yield a good enough fit.